# Pip install fails with “connection error" ssl problem

Tags: python, windows, ssl, pip, package

I am kind of new to Python and I started learning about packages and I tried to install some packages and update pip but I always get this error:

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/pip/
>
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/pip/
>
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/pip/
>
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/pip/
>
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/pip/
>
> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))

I tried to look online for a solution but anything I have tried by now has failed

**Edit**: solved it!

I have solved the problem and it was associated with my antivirus blocking pip. I have solved it by deleting my antivirus and everything works. Keep in mind that when I disable my antivirus and firewall, it didn't work and only worked when I deleted the antivirus completely.

I hope that if you have the same problem that will help you

Comment: What did you enter into the command line?

Comment: Is the data / time of your pc correct?

Answer (score 7):

Please try updating your pip using the trusted option:

```
pip install --upgrade pip --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
```

To make this setting permanent you can create a pip.ini file in your user folder that contains:

```
[global]
trusted-host = files.pythonhosted.org
```

Please note that this is a more generic solution, pointing to trust the fils.pythonhosted.org host.
It is important to investigate and understand the root cause of the issue (wrong time / date, for example, can be one of the possible ones).

Comment: thank you , this is working but i am looking for a premenet solution. can i apply this to trust this source by default?

Comment: So even after the pip update you still have the issue? Can you please share your Python / Pip / Windows version? And, also important, are you into a corporate network?

Comment: Another question, are you using tools like Fiddler? https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: so my pip version is 20.1.1 and i got python 3.8 and i got windows 10 pro v1903 (64 bit) , and i dont use tools like fidder

Comment: This is indeed very werid. You are not in a corporate network, right? Please try to add the pip.ini file as I suggested in my last update of the answer.

Comment: no i am not on any corporate network just my home network and i tried to add this folder before and it also dosent work , do you think that reinstall python worth a shot?

Comment: Sure and it doesn't cost much time!
Did you try the pip.ini file as I've suggested?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. any solution

Comment: Did you try the provided one, @SanthoshYedidi?
What output do you get?

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a clock misconfigured.

I fixed that following this tutorial:
[Network - NTP](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-ntp)

Check if your system clock is correct:

```
timedatectl status
```

```
Local time: Fr 2018-02-23 08:47:13 UTC
                   Universal time: Fr 2018-02-23 08:47:13 UTC
                         RTC time: Fr 2018-02-23 08:47:13
                        Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
        System clock synchronized: yes
 systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                  RTC in local TZ: no
```

If not, install chrony:

```
sudo apt install chrony
```

And start **chronyd** - the actual daemon to sync and serve via the NTP protocol

```
sudo chronyd
```